# iOS7 - UIWebView with contentInset doesn't show menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, ios7

I have a UIWebView that allows for content to be edited with another UIView included in the UIScrollView of the UIWebView. This creates a header above editable content. The editable content is positioned using a contentInset on the scrollview so that it's positioned correctly below the header.

Now - what I'm finding is that when the scroll view of a UIWebView has a contentInset applied to it that is > 0 then the menu that is shown (cut/copy/paste) etc is only shown when the insertion point from the top of the content inset is greater than the absolute value of the content inset.

So let's say the content inset is 100px. This means that the menu is only shown when the insertion point is > 100px from the start of the contentInset.

This is a regression from iOS6 where the menu was always shown. The same code shows the menu on iOS6, but when built for iOS7 it does not show the menu.

The only way to get the menu to appear is to move the insertion point down in the body of UIWebView.

Has anyone seen this or know of a fix to this problem? The only fix I can find is not to specify a contentInset which then of course breaks the app's usability...

Comment: The way that I fixed this was to use a CSS style to position the content editable DIV at the appropriate offset from the top of the screen. That way I don't rely on a contentInset to position the start of the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view = self.webView;
}
```

Works fine for me.